# Array args with host environment variables for vagrant shell provisioner?

Tags: ruby, vagrant, vagrantfile

I have the following in a Vagrantfile (vagrant 1.7.4),

```
arg1=ENV['LINUX_USERNAME']
arg2=ENV['LINUX_PASSWORD']

config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
  s.path="create_user.bash"
  s.args = [arg1, arg2]
end
```

Edit: Update missing information

I also have the following in a script called `install.bash`

```
echo ""
read -p "Linux username: " LINUX_USERNAME
read -s -p "Linux password: " LINUX_PASSWORD
echo ""
echo "export LINUX_USERNAME=$LINUX_USERNAME"
echo "export LINUX_PASSWORD=$LINUX_PASSWORD"

echo "Using Linux Username $LINUX_USERNAME"
echo "Using Linux Password $LINUX_PASSWORD"

vagrant up
```

I get the following error message when I run `install.bash`,

```
shell provisioner:
* Shell provisioner `args` must be a string or array.
```

I think perhaps the environment variables are not being read correctly during the vagrant up stage.  Note that this process does work if I set the environment variables at the command line and then run `vagrant up`

Comment: Try `s.args   = "#{ENV['LINUX_USERNAME']}, #{ENV['LINUX_PASSWORD']}"`.

Comment: only seems to work if each entry of the array is a string ``s.args = ["#{ENV['LINUX_USERNAME']}", "#{ENV['LINUX_PASSWORD']}"]``     might be a peculiarity of my setup

Comment: No, I can confirm this issue and your fix seems to avoid the problem.